# install4j GUI/Console mode testing automation

Tags: install4j

I started exploring the capabilities of install4j.  Are there any utilities/capabilities by which we can automate the testing of install4j GUI & consoles.

We have to come up with an installer that has pretty good number installer panels with multiple inputs and validations, so automating the testing of screens is a priority for us.

I see that installanywhere has a built in utility for this, is there a similar capability in install4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 6.1 there is no GUI testing functionality in install4j, it is planned to be implemented in a future version.

One way to do it at this point is by starting the installer in console mode (with the -c argument) and by using [expectj](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/) to drive the user input.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response